# How to make API request from react client to express server running on the Heroku platform

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, json-server

Ive been trying to deploy a Twitch like application using react, redux, node media server and json server module to Heroku. However, I keep running into a issue when trying to connect my react client and express server via a api request, during production.

Im trying to make the actual request through my action creators and by using axios with a base url of http://localhost:4000, however that only works on my local machine.

```
 const response = await streams.get("/streams");

 dispatch({ type: FETCH_STREAMS, payload: response.data });
};
```

You can view my full repo at https://github.com/XorinNebulas/Streamy

You can also view my current deployed version of the site on Heroku at 
https://streamy-app.herokuapp.com/

here is my api/server.js file. My express server will be watching on a random port equal to process.env.PORT, so I have no way of knowing how to make a network request via my action creators to that random port during production.

```
const path = require("path");
const cors = require("cors");
const jsonServer = require("json-server");
const server = jsonServer.create();
const router = jsonServer.router("db.json");
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults({
  static: "../client/build"
});
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

// Set default middlewares (logger, static, cors and no-cache)
server.use(cors());
server.use(middlewares);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Add custom routes before JSON Server router
  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, "../", "client", "build", "index.html")
    );
  });
}

// Use default router
server.use(router);
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`JSON Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I expected the request to go thru and load up some data from api/db.json, with a resquest url of https://streamy-app.herokuapp.com/streams but instead i got a request url of http://localhost:4000/streams, which of course leads to the CORS issue below

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:4000/streams. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I would truly appreciate any suggestions, been working on this for days.

Comment: Using Heroku's instance and running your API on my Ubuntu, at `http://localhost:4000/` - I couldn't reproduce the problem.
Can you share `Access-Control-*` headers of the response you've get?

Comment: when running the application locally in development mode. I'm able to get a status of 304 with response headers including,                                                `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000, and Cache-Control: no-cache.`

Comment: However i get, `No response data available for this request`, when deployed on Heroku in production mode. I also get no response headers. Hope this helps.

Comment: You are using two domains: the client served from Heroku is requesting API on `http://localhost:4000/`. Does anything run on your local machine on this port?

Comment: Yes i can easily run my express server locally and everything works fine, however users visiting the app cant accesses my json.db data because they are not on my localhost. I would like to make the request to my express server instance that is deployed to Heroku and listening on port process.env.PORT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright looks like I figured it out. I simply went into streams/client/package.json and added

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:4000"
```

I then went into streams\client\src and deleted the api folder which contained my custom axios with a base url. using instead axios out of the box for my action creators

```
const response = await axios.get("/streams");

 dispatch({ type: FETCH_STREAMS, payload: response.data });
};
```

Now while running locally in development mode, I'm able to make a request to http://localhost:4000/streams, but after deploying my node app to Heroku I successfully make a request over to https://streamy-app.herokuapp.com/streams 
hope this helps someone with slimier issues.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should know that Heroku **doesn't allow** to expose multiple ports, which means you should change the approach of multiple ports to something else (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37645044/5979775)).

Second, the file `client/src/apis/streams.js` is hard-coded configured to send requests to `http://localhost:4000/` - which is not a good idea.
Whatever approach you choose - even deploying to another host server - you will need to dynamically configure the API endpoint, per environment.

I would also recommend you to:

1. Change the way you deploy react, as explained [here](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-deploy-a-production-react-app-to-heroku-c4831dfcfa08).
2. After doing the above, consider consolidating your API service with the static server, so that you don't need multiple ports, and then everything becomes easier.

Comment: Thanks for the extra resources and all your help Avraham. It looks like I was able to finally resolve this issue.