# How do I redirect traffic from port 443 and 80 to my heroky app dyno?

Tags: java, http, heroku, https, port

I have setup java application on heroku. It needs to get traffic from port 443 and 80 (available ports to public on heroku) and needs to process it and send it back to the client after some operation. How do I redirect traffic from port 80 or 443 to my java application?

Client is netcat connecting to heroku

```
nc [server-ip] [port]
```

Port is provided to the java app by command line argument
java app code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Launcher {
    public static ArrayList<Thread> ClientThreads = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting Listener");

        int port;
        ServerSocket listener = null;

        // Parse Arguments
        for (String arg: args) {
            if (arg.contains("-h")) {
                System.out.println("Usage: listener [port]");
                return;
            } else {
                try {
                    port = Integer.parseInt(arg);
                    listener = new ServerSocket(port);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Invalid port");
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Port cannot be used. Try another port");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            int ThreadID = 0;
            while (true) {
                assert listener != null;
                Socket client = listener.accept();
                int finalThreadID = ThreadID;
                ClientThreads.add( new Thread(() -> HandleCon(client, finalThreadID), "Client-Thread-"+finalThreadID));
                ClientThreads.get(finalThreadID).start();
                ThreadID = ClientThreads.size() - 1;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Some error occurred");
        }

    }

    public static void HandleCon(Socket Client, int Id) {
        try {
            System.out.println(Client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " has connected");
            BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Client.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter Writer = new PrintWriter(Client.getOutputStream());
            while (true) {
                Writer.print("Enter a command: ");
                Writer.flush();
                String command = Reader.readLine();

                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                    System.out.println(Client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " has disconnected");
                    Client.close();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(Client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " -> " + command);
                Writer.println("You have entered " + command);
                Writer.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(Client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " has disconnected");
        }

        ClientThreads.remove(Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: "How do I redirect traffic from port 80 or 443 to my java application?"—I don't understand. Traffic from these ports gets routed to your application automatically, assuming you bind to the port given by the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: Chris, that was the part which I didn't know. Which was answered by the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Heroku you only get to assign one port. You cannot open new ports and the port number is random and fixed given to you by Heroku through an environment variable.

Port 80 and 443 are usually for http and https. Depending on your application you may be fine by just binding a single port.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications

When executing your program you need to pass `$PORT` to your application instead of specifying fixed port numbers.

If you need to have multiple ports for your application a similar question has been answered here: [Heroku + node.js: I have a server which uses multiple ports. How can I get Heroku to allocate them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636580/heroku-node-js-i-have-a-server-which-uses-multiple-ports-how-can-i-get-herok)