# Trouble Deploying Angular/Express App in Heroku frontend cannot hit the API endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, heroku, deployment

Currently in development it works just fine... `localhost:4200` for the front-end and `localhost:8080` for the back-end

However, I just deployed it and the front-end get displayed, but isn't getting the data from the API because in my `app.service.ts` I'm doing the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api'

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getNews() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/countries`)
  }
}
```

As you can see, I'm hardcoding the `localhost:8080` and it works fine in development, but when it comes to production Heroku does not assign me the `port 8080`, it assigns me another one.

That being said... How can I tweak this in order to read the port Heroku gives me?

This is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const scrapper = require('./backend/scrapper')

// Create link to Angular build directory
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/covid19";
app.use(express.static(distDir));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    next();
});

app.use("/api/countries", async (req, res, next) => {
    const data = await scrapper.getCountries()
    res.status(200).json(data)
})

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`API listening on port ${port}...`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

As you can see I'm declaring my port to be `process.env.PORT || 8080`, but this is for the backend... How can achieve this but in my API call in the `service.ts` file?

Comment: Well your api route isn't a localhost anymore when your are hosting it on heroku. Do you host the node js and the front-end in the same heroku application? Or do you have 2

Comment: Yes, all in the same Heroku App (backend and frontend). @Tom

Comment: Okay I don't think Heroku supports ports, according to this stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636580/heroku-node-js-i-have-a-server-which-uses-multiple-ports-how-can-i-get-herok. You have 2 options, have al ook at the answer of that stackoverflow or what you can do is create 2 heroku apps one with `front-end`, one with `back-end`. In your front-end you would then change your api url to something like `http://my-heroku.herokuapp.com`. Search around for how to host node.js server on Heroku, plenty of information to be found.

Answer (score 2):

You guys pointed me in the right direction, but to be precise:

I noticed that in Angular you get a `environments` folder with two files 1. `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`.

I just had to make sure to use to point to the URL that Heroku gave me for my app after deploying `yourappname.herokuapp.com`, by doing the following in my `environments.prod.ts` (Which is the one that Heroku is gonna look for)

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: "https://yourappname.herokuapp.com/api"
};
```

And in my `api.service.ts` I ended up with the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment'

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getNews() {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + '/countries')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy a web server on Heroku you bind to the `$PORT` Heroku tells you to bind to.

When you visit your deployed app you don't specify a port. You just connect to `yourappname.heroku.com`. The DNS automatically translates it into `ipaddress:port`.

So on your frontend you just point to `yourappname.heroku.com` instead of `ipaddress:port`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to the production variables when deploying your app. I like using the isDevMode function included in the '@angular/core' package.

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';

setUrl(){
 if(isDevMode() == true){
 //in development mode
 api_url = "localhost:4200"
 }else{
 api_url = "heroku.app_url.app"
 }
}
```

This function lets you know which mode the app is running in, so you can use that to switch between connection strings.