# Deploying GraphQL API with Socket.IO

Tags: heroku, socket.io, graphql

I am on my way to create a GraphQL API with Socket.IO.
As you guys most likely know, they both run on a port of their own.
If they run on two seperate ports, could this become a problem when deploying the API to Heroku?
I have been looking for an answer to this question but found none, and I don't want to start of my API project if it's not possible. I have deployed REST API's before, but that's just one port for the backend and one for the frontend but I am unsure about this working out in the end.

Comment: Maybe this thread is helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37636580/heroku-node-js-i-have-a-server-which-uses-multiple-ports-how-can-i-get-herok

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.